# How to use useEffect for a useState variable that has no dependency?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I'm creating a React form that has stores new product list in a local state i.e.

```
const [listItem, setListItem] = useState([]);
```

I have submit handlers where I append new value like-

```
const handleAddProduct = (data) => {
  setListItem ([...listItem], data)
  console.log('ListItems-', listItem); // my console log doesn't update state but in react debugger tool I do see it's updated.
}
```

How can use a useEffect so that it always updates state? P.S. - data is not a local state, it's confined to a certain block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Due to Reactjs's [update batching](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), you could not see your updated state within your event handler right after you updated it**

If you want to see your value change, place it before the return function of your component:

Something like this:

```
const handleAddProduct = (data) => {
    setListItem ([...listItem], data)
}

console.log('ListItems-', listItem);

return (
);
```

Answer (score 2):

State updates are asynchronous and will not reflect immediately. Only in next cycle. That is why you can check in useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log(listItem);
},[listItem]);
```

State is updating correctly.

Not related to the question but, if you are adding to array you might want to do this :

```
const handleAddProduct = (data) => {
setListItem ([...listItem, data]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it shows me following error- React hook useEffect was passed a dependency list that is not an array literal.

Comment: Fixed that. 2nd param should be an array